# Unable to use Dartpy Flutter package to run Python code in iOS and Android platforms

Tags: python, android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm getting below errors in Android and iOS when tried to use the Dartpy package.

Android :

```
E/flutter ( 9357): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: Permission denied
E/flutter ( 9357): Command: python3.10-config --ldflags --embed
```

iOS:

```
Exception has occurred. ProcessException (ProcessException: Starting new processes is not supported on iOS Command: python3.10-config --ldflags --embed)
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:dartpy/dartpy.dart';
 
void main() {
  //pyLibLocation = 'C:/Users/usename/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python312.dll' ;
  //pyLibLocation = 'ios_platform_path_dynamic_lib_python' ;
 
  dartpyc.Py_Initialize();
   final python = '''
   from time import time, ctime
   print("Today is", ctime(time()))
   ''';
   final pystring = python.toNativeUtf8();
   dartpyc.PyRun_SimpleString(pystring.cast<Char>());
   malloc.free(pystring);
   print(dartpyc.Py_FinalizeEx());
 
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

How to set pyLibLocation and where to get the Python dynamic library for Android and iOS specific to Dartpy package